# How do I use e-mail addresses as user names in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla1.5

I'm developing a web site with Joomla, and I want to use an e-mail address as a user name.

I tried to edit default.php and controller.php in com_user/register directory but that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [commercial plugin for that](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication/10343) (it costs £7 (UK) as of 8th February 2010), and a [non-commercial plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/authentication-external/6739) that does something similar.

Comment: Thank  you very much...
yes I already know it..but is there have any manual adjustment with out installing those plug ins...?
regards 
Umanda

Comment: @user268598 - given those plugins exist, I'm guessing it's non-trivial, but I don't know enough about Joomla to be sure.